# Как получить список файлов без расширения в папке?

Tags: c#, файлы, uwp, extension

Если использую

```
if (backupFolder != null)
{
    List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>
    {
        ".txt",
        ".rtf"
    };

    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions (CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank, fileTypeFilter);
    StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = backupFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();                

    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {

    }
}
```

то все работает. Как мне получить файлы без расширения?

спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
```

Comment: Это возвращает список файлов? И в UWP работает?

Comment: Почему список файлов то? Название же само за себя говорит.